# How to create a Rails model without an HTML view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a model that I only want to ever return JSON, regardless of any conneg or file-like extensions on the URI (e.g. `/app/model.json`). Google-fu is coming up short and this can't be that difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controllers you simple have to create a respond_to block that only responds to JSON:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @model }
end
```

Comment: That's what I have now. so /app/model.json will return JSON but /app/model raises ActionController::UnknownFormat in InterestsController#index. So how to make json the default?

Comment: Then you need to do it in your routing: `resources :model, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }`

Comment: That's the sauce I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a decision made by the controller, not because there is/is not a model or view present. In your [controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data) you can:

```
render json: @your_model
```

However you will quickly find that the default implementation of `to_json` (which is what is used internally, above) can be annoying hard to do exactly what you want. When you reach that point you can use [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to create views that massage the JSON from your model(s) exactly as you want.